# nlog rules not honored -- writing to my database log

Tags: database, config, nlog

I know there's a bunch in here that's redundant, but out of desperation, trying everything to prevent logging:

**My nlog rules section is:**

```
<rules>
<logger name="cfm" minlevel="Info" writeTo="cfmdatabase,console" final="true"/>
<logger name="db" minlevel="Info" writeTo="database,console" final="true"/>

<logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="database,console" final="false"/>
<logger name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="database,console" final="false"/>
<logger name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="database,console" final="false"/>
<logger name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.*" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="database,console" final="false"/>
<logger name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR" minlevel="Info" writeTo="console" final="false"/>
<logger name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware" minlevel="Info" writeTo="console" final="true"/>
<logger name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware" maxlevel="Info" final="true" />

<logger name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="console" final="false"/>
<logger name="System.*" finalMinLevel="Warn" maxlevel="Info" final="true" />

<!--Skip non-critical Microsoft logs and so log only own logs (BlackHole) -->
<logger name="Microsoft.*" finalMinLevel="Warn" maxlevel="Info" final="true" />

<logger name="Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime" finalMinLevel="Info" minlevel="Info" final="true" />
</rules>
```

YET: I'm getting logs to the database
**Logger:** Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware
**Level**:Info

What am I doing wrong?

I expect there to be no entries in the database log for anything from logger Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware

Answer (score 0):

NLog evaluates the logging rules from top to bottom, and when meeting your 3rd logging-rule, then it states:

- Any `logger name="*"` with `minlevel="Info"`should `writeTo="database,console"`

```xml
<rules>
<logger name="cfm" minlevel="Info" writeTo="cfmdatabase,console" final="true"/>
<logger name="db" minlevel="Info" writeTo="database,console" final="true"/>

<logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="database,console" final="false"/>
```

Consider moving your `finalMinLevel`-filters to the top, and have the catch-all at the bottom:

```xml
<rules>
<logger name="cfm" minlevel="Info" writeTo="cfmdatabase,console" final="true"/>
<logger name="db" minlevel="Info" writeTo="database,console" final="true"/>

<logger name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="console" />
<logger name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="console" />

<!--Skip non-critical Microsoft logs and so log only own logs -->
<logger name="Microsoft.*" finalMinLevel="Warn" />
<logger name="Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime" finalMinLevel="Info" />
<logger name="System.*" finalMinLevel="Warn" />

<logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="database,console" />
</rules>
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-Rules-FinalMinLevel